# FadeTO is not working with IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

Am using `fadeTo()` to hide div.This is working pretty well in Mozilla. But in IE8 it is not hiding that div. Here is my code

```
$(".Status").change(function(){
    var value = $("#check").val();
    if(value == undefined || value == ''){
     $("#DelayOptionDiv").fadeTo(200, 0);
    }
    else if(value == 'on'){
     $("#DelayOptionDiv").fadeTo(200, 1);

});
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Which jQuery version? Any error in console?

Comment: IE??? Seriously. It just sucks and is a headache for webdevs. Develop a website for all, and invest precious time for **IE** site. Arrggh. *Ok, that's just me ;)*

Comment: @AmitJoki That's just your opinion, imho ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff, I am always bad at shortforms. So what does imho mean?

Comment: "In my honest opinion" - I think

Comment: @AmitJoki "in my humble opinion"

Comment: Well fack me... My whole life has been a lie!

Comment: @ Wolff thnsk for response am using jquery-1.10.1

Comment: @user3132347 So it should work! Now try to replicate your issue in jsfiddle and please post any error message, if any (check console in IE8)

Comment: Wait, is `#check` a checkbox? If ya, then you should check it using: `if($("#check").checked) {
    /*...*/
}
else {
    /*...*/
}`

Comment: @Wolff #check is text field.

Comment: can any one please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by adding a filter for IE8.

Ex: `$('DelayOptionDiv').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=40)');`

Comment: jQuery 1.x handles it for IE8

Comment: @scripto thanks for your reply..but unfortunately css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=40)');  is not working..:(